# How to add checkbox at specific row and column?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I want to add checkbox in a specific row and column but i'm always stumbled upon this error

> "System.FormatException: Formatted value of the cell has a wrong
>   type."

And here is my code to add the checkbox;

```
    private void checkboxSource(string columnSource, int n)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
        checkboxColumn.FalseValue = "0";
        checkboxColumn.TrueValue = "1";
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6] = checkboxColumn;
    }
```

I know something is wrong when i try to bind `checkboxColumn` to datagridview. Can someone please guide me on how to bind the checkbox to datagridview properly provided which row and cell are taken into account. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the cell contains null value. You should set [`Style.NullValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of the cell to `false`. The property sets the display value when cell value is `DBNull.Value` or `null`:

```
var cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
{
    TrueValue = "1",
    FalseValue = "0",
};
cell.Style.NullValue = false;
this.dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0] = cell;
```

Comment: Usually you should create a column of type `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` instead of changing the cell type. But if for some reason you need to change a specific cell type, you can change the cell type.